# ASP.NET vs Infopath for forms

Tags: asp.net, infopath

We use Infopath at work, quite frequently for form design and then we integrate this into MOSS 2007.

What I don't yet know is what advantages are there to designing a form in Infopath as opposed to making a webpage (eg ASP.NET/C#) to allow for the same intention?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only used InfoPath for one or two things in MOSS.  It seems to me that InfoPath is a bit more integrated into MOSS than trying to use .Net webforms from a data retrieval/modification standpoint.  That being said, virtually everything we have been doing in SharePoint lately that isn't easily done in a webpart has been done through .Net webforms.

From a flexibility standpoint I think you have more options with the .Net framework then what you get in InfoPath, especially if we have to use multiple form that interact with one another almost like an embedded SharePoint webapp.

Comment: I noticed that css styling in Infopath is not fully supported, but I found a hack to sort that.

Answer (score 2):

Maintenance is easer, integration with sharepoint is easier,database submission/retrieval is easier, and workflows are easier with infoPath.
Customization is more robust, and database submission/retrieval is more robust in asp.net.

Basically, use infoPath if it's easy.  Use C# if it contains a lot of custom things.